# Show contact number in my own listview in android 2.1

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to android and I want to display a contact number from phone book in my own listview. I had achieved to display the name but when I am trying to display the number then it returns the Boolean number that is 1 or 0.

My code is

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {
    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID,  
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
            Contacts.STARRED,  
            Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED,  
            Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,  
            Contacts.PHOTO_ID,  
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,  
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER                  
    };

    static final int SUMMARY_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;
    static final int SUMMARY_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;
    static final int SUMMARY_STARRED_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;
    static final int SUMMARY_TIMES_CONTACTED_COLUMN_INDEX = 3;
    static final int SUMMARY_PRESENCE_STATUS_COLUMN_INDEX = 4;
    static final int SUMMARY_PHOTO_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 5;
    static final int SUMMARY_LOOKUP_KEY = 6;
    static final int SUMMARY_HAS_PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX = 7;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
        Cursor c =
                getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        startManagingCursor(c);



        ContactListItemAdapter adapter = new ContactListItemAdapter(this, R.layout.main, c);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private final class ContactListItemAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
        public ContactListItemAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
            super(context, layout, c);
        }


        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            final ContactListItemCache cache = (ContactListItemCache) view.getTag();

            cursor.copyStringToBuffer(SUMMARY_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX, cache.nameBuffer);
            int size = cache.nameBuffer.sizeCopied;

            cursor.copyStringToBuffer(SUMMARY_HAS_PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX, cache.numberView);
            int number = cache.numberView.sizeCopied;


            cache.nameView.setText(cache.nameBuffer.data, 0, size);
            cache.numView.setText(cache.numberView.data, 0, number);
            final long contactId = cursor.getLong(SUMMARY_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
            final String lookupKey = cursor.getString(SUMMARY_LOOKUP_KEY);
            cache.photoView.assignContactUri(Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey));

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
            ContactListItemCache cache = new ContactListItemCache();
            cache.nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            cache.numView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);
            cache.photoView = (QuickContactBadge) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
            view.setTag(cache);

            return view;
        }
    }

    final static class ContactListItemCache {
        public TextView nameView;
        public TextView numView;
        public CharArrayBuffer numberView = new CharArrayBuffer(128);
        public QuickContactBadge photoView;
        public CharArrayBuffer nameBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(128);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

See my updated code ->

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ContentResolver cr = new ContentResolver(this.getApplicationContext()) {
    };

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", null, null);

    phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    ContactListItemAdapter adapter = new ContactListItemAdapter(this, R.layout.main, phones);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

But it shows error. Help me to solve this!

thanks....

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question.

Comment: If you are new then please spend time reading our [FAQ] and also this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites before asking any more questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER will return you weather the contact has Phone Number or not. to get actual phone number use

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
```

Use below code to get the information about all the contact. i. e use this URI

```
 Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", "your contact id", null);

    phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

so you can use this code while you are querying contact database in OnCreate()

---

***Updated Answer***

In your OnCreate() you are querying the database with Phone NUmber and display name. but now you need to modify the query in such way that you will get **contact id** too.

for that purpose you just need to add the ID field in your contacts select query.

```
 String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ) AND (" + Contacts._ID + " NOTNULL ))";
        Cursor c =
                getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

After getting this Cursor you need to get the Contact id from this cursor and pass that id to below query

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", "Put the contact id here", null);

phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

Comment: thanks for reply Drax but i am not getting where to put this line in my code.

Comment: hy again thanks.. please can u tell me what is cr in Cursor phones = cr.query ? it is an object of ?

Comment: i have just update my code, please have a look on that and i am getting error at Content Resolver. Thanks

Comment: This is like in the contact database the phone number is stored in different tables so we need to query that table with proper contact id. i am editing my Answer please go through it

Comment: i had tried with the code given by you. but it is again giving the error.. :( if it is possible to you to give me your Email ID than please give me so that i can send u the whole project, and then you can change in that as par requirement.

Comment: this ID -> "dsprajapati@blogspot.com " if any other one then please let me know.

Comment: dude this is not email id.. this is link of my blog. email id is dineshprjpt@gmail.com

Comment: Okey.. i just sent again... please have a look on that... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This does not look right to me:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ number,
```

How does `number` relate to the `CONTACT_ID`?

Comment: thanks for reply.. can you please tell me that what are the changes require ?